# A server behind a physical Tor gateway to hide its location

Tags: onion-services, security, deanonymization

Is is technically possible to run a server, that is accessible only through Tor via SSH, and be able to hide its physical location from an adversary who happens to gain a root access?

In my world-view a common technique to discover a physical location of a computer is by looking at its "public" IP and query a geolocation database. A computer is unable to determine its "public" address unless he asks another computer on the Internet.

So is it safe to assume that by placing the server between a physical Tor gateway (i.e. OpenWrt router) and a router I could protect it from being discovered since all traffic would go through the gateway?

When I am talking about a Tor gateway I mean existing solutions such as anonabox.

Comment: What you're describing is basically Whonix?

Comment: I am aware that Whonix is using a term "gateway" but I was not able to verify whether it protects a "workstation" vm against a physical discovery. Is it documented somewhere? I though it's designed this way so the tor daemon runs in a separate virtual machine in case there's an unpatched vulnerability.

Comment: That's basically the some protection except using  virtual machines and not physical ones. The concept is the same with physical machines. See: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/IsolatingProxy

Answer (score 2):

[Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/) is what you want.

> The Workstation VM can "see" only IP addresses on the Internal LAN,
>   which are the same in every Whonix installation. User applications
>   therefore have no knowledge of the user's "real" IP address, nor do
>   they have access to any information about the physical hardware. In
>   order to obtain such information, an application would have to find a
>   way "break out" of VirtualBox, or to subvert the Gateway (perhaps
>   through a bug in Tor or the Gateway's Linux kernel).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whonix